# Solr not found error only in production mode, but works on development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr

Here's my environment

- Ubuntu (14.04)
- Rails (4.1.6)
- sunspot (2.1.1)
- sunspot_rails (2.1.1)
- sunspot_solr (2.1.1)

### I got not found error, when I did solr:reindex under `production mode`, but works on development mode

```
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     Not Found

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Tool\\:\\:Cvt\\:\\:RemoteFocu</query></delete>"
```

I've googled many solutions

Most solutions are about

- stop solr
- remove solr
- remove solr folder
- reinstall solr
- start solr

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found you need to change the `path` in  `sunspot.yml`

Because there is no production folder under the solr on my ubuntu, only `default` folder

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    #path: /solr/production
    path: /solr/default
```